# PHP : How to fix array_pop and the value 0

Tags: php, arrays, array-population

I´m trying from various paths to generate a dimensional array.
For that, I´m using the function found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579305/how-to-merge-multiple-url-path-into-multidimensional-array?noredirect=1&lq=1).

**My code**

```
function get_dir_content_to_array( string $dir_path, string $dir_filter = null, string $file_filter = null ) {
    if( is_dir_empty( $dir_path ) )
        return false;
    $output = array();
    $files = get_subdir_filtered( $dir_path, $dir_filter, $file_filter );
    if ( isset( $files ) ) {
        foreach ( $files as $name => $object ) {
            if ( $object->getFilename() !== "." && $object->getFilename() !== ".." ) {
                // Split by the delimiter.
                $delimiter       = "/";
                $name            = str_replace( "\\", $delimiter, $name );
                $relative_path   = str_replace( $dir_path, "", $name );
                $a_relative_path = explode( $delimiter, $relative_path );
                $path = [ array_pop( $a_relative_path ) ];
                foreach ( array_reverse( $a_relative_path ) as $pathPart ) {
                    $path = [ $pathPart => $path ];
                }

                // Add it to a temp list.
                $paths[] = $path;
            }
            $output = call_user_func_array( 'array_merge_recursive', $paths );

        }
    }
    return $output;
}

function get_subdir_filtered( $dir_path, $dir_filter, $file_filter ) {
    $path      = realpath( $dir_path );
    $directory = new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $path );
    $files = null;
    if ( ! empty( $dir_filter ) || ! empty( $file_filter ) ) {
        if ( ! empty( $dir_filter ) ) {
            $filter = new DirnameFilter( $directory, $dir_filter );
        }
        if ( ! empty( $file_filter ) ) {
            $filter = new FilenameFilter( $filter, $file_filter );
        }
        $files = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator( $filter );
    } else {
        $files = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator( $directory );
    }
    return $files;
}

class DirnameFilter extends FilesystemRegexFilter {
    // Filter directories against the regex
    public function accept() {
        return ( ! $this->isDir() || preg_match( $this->regex, $this->getFilename() ) );
    }
}
```

That works except when a folder is named "0"

How can I fixed that ? 
Why array_pop skip the value "0" even if it´s a string ?

Comment: Using the example from the linked question, this seems to work fine even if the directory name is "0".

Comment: @cmbuckley, Thanks a lot ! I´m really tired. The problem is because of the result passed by `json_encode` which removes the zero key.

Comment: Please add that to the question.

Answer (score 2):

When `json_encode()` encodes an array whose keys are sequential integers starting from `0`, or the string equivalents of them, it produces a JSON array rather than an object.

You could use the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` flag, but this will then turn the arrays of filenames inside a folder into objects, which you don't want.

What you can do is use a PHP object instead of an array to represent a folder. `json_encode()` will encode this as an object, even if it has numeric properties.

I think this might do it:

```
function get_dir_content_to_array( string $dir_path, string $dir_filter = null, string $file_filter = null ) {
    if( is_dir_empty( $dir_path ) )
        return false;
    $output = array();
    $files = get_subdir_filtered( $dir_path, $dir_filter, $file_filter );
    if ( isset( $files ) ) {
        foreach ( $files as $name => $object ) {
            if ( $object->getFilename() !== "." && $object->getFilename() !== ".." ) {
                // Split by the delimiter.
                $delimiter       = "/";
                $name            = str_replace( "\\", $delimiter, $name );
                $relative_path   = str_replace( $dir_path, "", $name );
                $a_relative_path = explode( $delimiter, $relative_path );
                $path = [ array_pop( $a_relative_path ) ];
                foreach ( array_reverse( $a_relative_path ) as $pathPart ) {
                    $folder = new StdClass;
                    $folder->{$pathPart} = $path;
                    $path = $folder;
                }

                // Add it to a temp list.
                $paths[] = $path;
            }
            $output = call_user_func_array( 'array_merge_recursive', $paths);

        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

I haven't tested it because I don't have the `get_subdir_filtered()` function. It's possible that `array_merge_recursive` won't do the correct merge of this. You might need to merge the objects, too. [This tutorial](https://ua1.us/news/tutorials/tutorial-how-to-recursively-merge-two-objects-in-php/) contains an implementation of `mergeObjectsRecursively` that I think should be a useful substitute.

Comment: I used `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` but my problem is this following one : `/0/1/0/filename.zip` return this : `a:1:{i:0;a:1:{i:1;a:1:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;s:23:"filename.zip";}}}}` so with one file more inside the root, I got this : `{"0":"update.json","1":{"1":{"0":{"0":"filename.zip"}}}}` instead of `{"0":"update.json","1":{"0":{"1":{"0":"filename.zip"}}}}`

Comment: You're mixing real arrays and associative arrays that should have "0"` as the key? That's tougher.

Comment: Yes, it´s a little messy. I don´t know if I should modify `get_dir_content_to_array` and makes a different structure or array or choose the correct option for `json_encode`.

Comment: If I do a hack : `$path = [ "_" . $pathPart => $path ];`, that works of course but with an undersore.

Comment: That does not work for the moment. I added the full code to help to test it. I got this result : `O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:1:"0";O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:1:"1";O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:1:"0";O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:23:"filename.zip";a:1:{i:0;N;}}}}}` and with `json_encode` gives a `null` result.

Comment: The problem seems happen during the merge with `array_merge_recursive`

Comment: Did you read the part of the answer where I said that part might not work, and you need to use `mergeObjectRecursively` instead?

Comment: ah ok, I did not see. I will try this.

Comment: I thought it works, but in some cases, that does not work like if you have `0/1/file.zip` and `0/1/3/file.zip` the merge generates `O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:1:"0";O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:1:"1";s:32:"file_0.1.zip";}s:1:"1";O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:1:"1";O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:1:"3";s:35:"file_0.1.3.zip";}}}`  The problem is always the same, when you try to cast the zero value as a string, the "0" becomes an integer after to cast the object as an array. If you do `$folder->{ "_" . $pathPart} = $path;`, that merges perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got this path :  `update.json and 0/1/0/filename.zip`

As @Barmar said, basically, the problem is when I try to convert an array to a json object.

> In PHP, an array is in fact, all the time an object so... $arr = [ "0" => [ "1" => ... ] ] for php, is equal to : $arr = [ 0 => [ 1 => ... ] ]. In PHP 7.2.x, each time you will merge objects, The `"0"` as string key will be cast to `0` as int.

**Consequences**

1 . with json_encode

```
echo json_encode( get_dir_content_to_array(...) );

//result = ["update.json",{"1":[["filename.zip"]]}]
```

2 . with json_encode and `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`

```
echo json_encode( get_dir_content_to_array(...), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT );

//result = {"0":"update.json","1":{"1":{"0":{"0":"filename.zip"}}}}
//I got 1,0,0,filename.zip instead of 0,1,0,filename.zip
```

3 . Add (string)

```
 $path = [array_pop( $a_relative_path)];
 foreach ( array_reverse( $a_relative_path ) as $pathPart ) {
    $path = [ (string) $pathPart => $path ];
 }
 //Same result of 2.
```

To keep the right order for the path, I found for the moment a hacky solution :

> Add underscore before each key

```
foreach ( array_reverse(  $a_relative_path ) as $pathPart ) {
    $path = [ "_" .  $a_relative_path => $path ];
}
//result = {"0":"update.json", "_0":{"_1":{"_0":{"0":"filenamezip"}}}} 

//With a new file path, I got this :
// {"0":"update.json","_toto":{"_foo":{"0":"test.txt"}},"_0":{"_1":{"_0":{"0":"filename.zip"}}}}
```

This solution is a hack, but I can make a difference between a kee which is a path `"_0":{"_1":{"_0"` and a key to index a file  `"0":"filename.zip"`

Comment: Your result has keys `"0"` and `"_0"`, something seems wrong with that. I think the problem may be that you're trying to mix indexed and keyed data in the same object.

Comment: Yes, you´re all right. There is a mix indexed. That´s why I add an underscore to make the difference between the key which is a dirname "_0", "_1" and the 0,1,2... which is a common indexation. The other way could be to do a bigger object where the dirname is a value and keys could be "dir" or "file" or something like that.