# create multidimensional array-Structure based on other Array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

How to handle if I want to create an array like in following example:

```
$value="test";
$array=[];
$path=[2,17,513];
```

Now, I want to build an array based on the available data which should look like:

```
$array['2']['17']['513']='test';
```

Anyone any idea?

I tried array_shift to prepare but I miss the point where the single array data will be transformed to an array key....

Comment: Is there always 3 items in the `$path` array?

Comment: if not, you could build a recursive function. Could you provide us more details? With more lines in $array, $path? Ty

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49563971, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579305/

Answer (score -1):

```
$value="test";
$array=[];
$path = [2, 17, 513];

[$a, $b, $c] = explode(",", $path);


$array[$a][$b][$c] = $value;


print_r($array[$a][$b][$c]); //returns 'test'
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation for your code. Either in the code itself or outside of it.