# Converting list of URLs into structured nested array

Tags: php

I have a list of URL strings:

```
'page1',
'page1/url1',
'page1/url2/suburl1',
'page2/url3',
'page2/url4/suburl2',
'page2/url4/suburl3'
```

And I want to convert it to a nested URL according to their structure:

```
Array
(
    [page1] => Array
        (
            [0] => "url1"
            [1] => Array 
                    (
                        [url2] => Array 
                                   ( 
                                      [0] => "suburl1" 
                                   )
                    )
        )
    [page2] => Array
        (
            [0] => "url3"
            [1] => Array 
                    (
                        [url4] => Array 
                            (
                                [0] => "suburl2"
                                [1] => "suburl3"
                            )
                    )
        )
                    
)
```

I've seen this question: [how to merge multiple url/path into multidimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579305/how-to-merge-multiple-url-path-into-multidimensional-array)
But it doesn't work in my case where the URLs are not the same dimension and also when I have URL like `page1` and not `/page1` it breaks it and create a string key and also an array key with that URL:

```
$urls = [
'page1',
'page1/url1',
'page1/url2/suburl1',
'page2/url3',
'page2/url4/suburl2',
'page2/url4/suburl3'
];

$paths = [];
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $path_parts = explode('/', $url);
    $path = [array_pop($path_parts)];
    foreach (array_reverse($path_parts) as $path_part) {
        $path = [$path_part => $path];
    }    
    $paths[] = $path;
}

$tree = call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $paths);

print_r($tree);
```

(Demo: https://onlinephp.io/c/02a524)

You can see for example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => page1
    [page1] => Array
```

Comment: Please provide your code within the question as well, otherwise it can be deemed off topic (see the [help/on-topic])

Answer (score 1):

You could try with:

```
<?php

$urls = [
    'page1',
    'page1/url1',
    'page1/url2/suburl1',
    'page2/url3',
    'page2/url4/suburl2',
    'page2/url4/suburl3'
];

function insert(&$array, $keys) {
    $key = array_shift($keys);
    if(empty($keys)) {
        if(!isset($array[$key])) {
            $array[] = $key;
        }
    } else {
        if(!isset($array[$key]) || !is_array($array[$key])) {
            $array[$key] = [];
        }
        insert($array[$key], $keys);
    }
}

// Sort and filter the URLs
sort($urls);
$urls = array_filter($urls, function($url) {
    return substr_count($url, '/') > 0;
});

$result = [];
foreach($urls as $url) {
    $parts = explode('/', $url);
    insert($result, $parts);
}

print_r($result);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [page1] => Array
        (
            [0] => url1
            [url2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => suburl1
                )

        )

    [page2] => Array
        (
            [0] => url3
            [url4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => suburl2
                    [1] => suburl3
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: thanks! It does work, but, is there a way make the "base" url as a value inside the array if it exists? For example for `page1`, since the base exists, it would be inside the `[page1] => '/'`, instead of twice both outside and as the array key?

Comment: Because right now it still does the double issue as in my example at the bottom of the post for the inner urls

Comment: Post desired output, now I'm following the current one.

Comment: If you are talking about "[0] => page1", check updated answer.

Comment: Thank you! There are a few issues with the updated code: It ignores URLs that have no sub-urls, and also, it still adds double values for the inner arrays. For example, it both adds `[0] => 'url1'` and also `[url1] => array(..)`. Example: https://onlinephp.io/c/e9e43